# Multiple canvases vs single canvases?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I've seen people using multiple canvas instead of a single one. Why? Is there better performance? I haven't seen much of a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple canvas are usually used when:

- their framerate is different from each other. As an example, consider a canvas where a game main screen is displayed and another canvas where the inventory is displayed. The game should be constantly updated, but the inventory may be static (or less frequently updated).
- it would be harder to correctly position all the elements in just one canvas. In these cases, the combination multiple canvas + CSS is generally used to make positioning substantially easier.
- a more flexible layout is required. As an example, consider that previous scenario that I made (a game screen and the inventory). Supposing that the player wants to hide his inventory, it would be much easier to accomplish this by using multiple canvas (you can just hide the canvas where the inventory is at (using javascript)). If only one canvas would be used in this case, it could potentially require a much bigger code and cause you a lot of bugs and frustration.